# Simulate mouse on Mac

Tags: iphone, macos, mouse, mouseevent

I have a virtual trackpad on my iPhone and to move my mouse I'm using :

```
CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(kCGDirectMainDisplay, CGPointMake(((float)aD.msg)+location.x, ((float)aD.msg2)+location.y));
```

It's working well but this not a real mouse because when I put my mouse on my hidden dock, this one doesn't display it self. I don't understand why.
More over I tried to simulate mouse click with :

```
case MOUSECLICK:
[self postMouseEventWithButton:0 withType:kCGEventLeftMouseDown andPoint:CGEventGetLocation(CGEventCreate(NULL))];
[self postMouseEventWithButton:0 withType:kCGEventLeftMouseUp andPoint:CGEventGetLocation(CGEventCreate(NULL))];
```

// *********************

-(void)postMouseEventWithButton:(CGMouseButton)b withType:(CGEventType)t andPoint:(CGPoint)p
{
    CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, t, p, b);
    CGEventSetType(theEvent, t);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
    CFRelease(theEvent);
}

Is it the good method? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint()` only moves the image of the cursor, it does not generate any events. You should create and post mouse events of type `kCGEventMouseMoved` to simulate moving the mouse. Your own method would do it:

```
[self postMouseEventWithButton:0 withType:kCGEventMouseMoved andPoint:point];
```

For clicks, you are already doing it the right way, I think. One thing you should also do is set the click count properly on both the mouse down and mouse up events, like so:

```
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, kCGMouseEventClickState, 1);
```

... because some applications need it.

(See also [Simulating mouse clicks on Mac OS X does not work for some applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369806/simulating-mouse-clicks-on-mac-os-x-does-not-work-for-some-applications/))

If your code doesn't work, I'm not sure why; it looks OK to me. Try posting to `kCGSessionEventTap` instead of `kCGHIDEventTap` and see if it helps. Also, you don't need the `CGEventSetType()` call since the type is already set in the creation call.

Comment: Thanks so I wrote : 
-(void)postMouseEventWithButton:(CGMouseButton)b withType:(CGEventType)t andPoint:(CGPoint)p
{
    CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, t, p, b);
    CGEventSetType(theEvent, t);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
 CGEventSetIntegerValueField(theEvent, kCGMouseEventClickState, 1);
    CFRelease(theEvent);
}

but nothing has changed. And I don't understand why CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint is working bad (dock problem etc). 
Have you got an idea?